# Is there any way to modify Examples in cucumber Scenario Outline such that params defined in a feature file take values from a DB table?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

Let's say I have a feature file like this.
Scenario Outline:Login
When user enters"
And enters ""
Then user is successfully logged in
Examples:
|username|password|
|abc|cde|

Now as per the cucumber implementation, username and password params will take value from examples table and scenario will be executed.
Instead of examples is there any other way to pass this data to params directly from data base without changing step definition for this feature file ??

Expecting passing data to parameters defined in the feature file directly from the DB without changing step definition code